# SQL Server 2008 R2 error: 18456, state 1: login failed for "domain\username"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

I can't seem to authenticate to my SQL server using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -d mydatabase -U user -P password
```

It always says, `error: 18456, state 1: login failed for "domain\username"`

What is weird is that if I test my connection through ODBC with the same credentials it authenticates fine.  In the management studio the account I'm using has the dbo_owner privileges on the instance and the database.  Also I connect to the instance using those same credentials.

In my event log I also have this error:

`Login failed for 'domain\username'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database [CLIENT MY_IPADDRESS]`

I'm no SQL expert and could use some help troubleshooting this if possible.

Comment: There should be an error in the event log as well that looks like `Error: 18456, Severity: #, State: #.` What's that one look like? You will always receive a `state 1` error from the command line. The state error indicates the source of the problem.

Comment: @Cole there is no `state` field in the event log.  The only other info is `level 4` and `task 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a Windows login with the `-U` parameter.  `-U` is for SQL logins.  If you want to connect as the currently logged in Windows user use the `-E` parameter to indicate you want to use a trusted connection.

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -d mydatabase -E
```

If you want to connect as a different windows user then you can run your shell (cmd, powershell, etc) as that user and use the above command.

Comment: Doing this still gives me the same error in addition to a new error `MSG 4060, Level 11, State 1`

Comment: @inquisitor Can you add the exact command you're typing in?  Your id has access to the database?